# Why does $\sum_{i=1}^x \frac xi - \lfloor \frac xi \rceil \approx 0.03648x$ instead of $x(1-2\gamma)$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, harmonic-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

Consider the following serie:
$\sum_{i=1}^x \lfloor \frac xi \rfloor = \sum_{i=1}^x \sigma(x)$
Where $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of divisors function.
 This is easy to understand because if you take for example x=31, you would do $\frac {31}{1}=31 $ which means that there is 31 multiples of 1 from 1 to 31, $\frac {31}{2}=15\frac {1}{2} $, wich means that there is 15 multiples of 2, and that we are halfway to the next multiple of 2, and so on. Using the floor function, we get the exact number of multiples of each integers from 1 to x that are in that same range.

There is no explicit formula to calculate this sum, because of the floor function, but we can approximate: 
$\sum_{i=1}^x \frac xi = x\sum_{i=1}^x \frac 1i = xH(x) \approx x(ln(x)+\gamma)$

So i got interested in the part that was removed by the floor function:
$\sum_{i=1}^x \frac xi - \lfloor \frac xi \rfloor$

and realised that it can be approximate because when x gets bigger, the part removed by the floor function converge to $ x(1-\gamma)$.

I aslo tried to the same logic for the ceiling function and the result makes sens:

$\sum_{i=1}^x \frac xi - \lfloor \frac xi \rfloor \approx x(1-\gamma)$
$\sum_{i=1}^x \frac xi - \lceil \frac xi \rceil \approx -\gamma x$

I did found documentation for all of this on the web, like the Dirichlet's asymptotic formula (http://dlmf.nist.gov/27.11), but i got confused when i tried it with the standard round function. At first, i thought that the result would be right between $x(1-\gamma)$ and $-\gamma x$, so $x(1-2\gamma)$ but instead, the part removed by the round function converge to 0.03648 * x... I did not found anything on the web about this number, and i cant find any relation to the $\gamma$ constant. I did not paid much attention to it until i saw it for a 2nd time, when i tried this:
$\sum_{i=1}^x \frac {1}{i} - ln(x) \approx \gamma$ 
$\sum_{i=1}^x \frac {1}{i+1} - ln(x) \approx \gamma-1$ 
$\sum_{i=1}^x \frac {1}{i+\frac{1}{2}} - ln(x) \approx -0.03648$

Can someone explain this behavior ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{i+\frac12}=2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{2i+1}=2\sum_{i=2}^{2n}\frac1i-2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{2i}=2H_{2n}-2-H_n=2\ln 2n+2\gamma-\ln n-\gamma\\
=\ln n+2\ln2-2+\gamma\approx \ln n-0.0364899739786$$

Comment: this is accurate, but i just edited because i made a mistake. The result i get for the round function is positive and is 0.036484913. Maybe i did not compute enough because i must admit it is pretty close, but i still dont understand. The numbers in the sum are the same whether we use the round, ceil or floor function. The floor function brings them all to the nearest smaller integer, and the ceiling function to the nearest bigger integer. it still means that the round function tend to round down more often than up. And it fact it does. in my test, the number is rounded down 62.97% of the time

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé: all the figures I am giving for the half-integer summation are exact. How many terms are you computing ?

Comment: yes this is ok for the half-integer summation, but for: $\sum_{i=1}^x \frac xi - \lfloor \frac xi \rceil$, i computed to x=15,000,000 and it gives me 0.036484913... Its still running and at the current rate, it really dont looks like that 2nd 4 is ever going to move.. Anyway your answer explain the second part with the sum of half-integer, and it also could explain the other part. I'll wait a little more before accepting the answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In the same spirit as Yves Daoust's answer
$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{i+\frac12}=H_{n+\frac{1}{2}}-2+\log (4)$$ where appear generalized harmonic numbers. For large values of $n$, using the asymptotics
$$S_n=\log \left({n}\right)+\gamma -2+\log
   (4)+\frac{1}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$